# Intellij IDEA. Hide .iml files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA 12 and I want to hide `.iml` files in Project view. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Check “Ignored files and folders” in [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-types.html) settings:

> **File | Settings | Editor | File Types** for Windows and Linux
>
> **IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | File Types** for OS X

Then add **`*.iml;*.idea;`** in the text box in the bottom:

[image: Hide Files and Folders in Intellij]

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/intellij-idea-does-not-show-some-files-know-the-hiding-places/

Comment: That does not work as *iml is reserved for Idea Module

Comment: @nick4fake just FYI - adding patterns there worked for me in 14.1.5

Comment: This does not seem to work for mac intelliJ 14, it does not hide files in the project view, I can still see them. I have some special .*.expl files that I would like to hide

Comment: I tried to ignore .class file using this method. Bad idea, Intellij even ignores .class files from jar libs...

Comment: Thanks, works on IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 Mac OS X 10.11.1

Comment: Seems not to be working on Intellij IDEA 2017.1.3 Trial version on Windows 10.

Comment: Make sure you use a Semicolon not a Comma or else it will not work.

Comment: Is this setting will block to add into git?

Comment: Works great when wanting to filter .bak files as well.
And you can always add the file to git manually by using the command prompt (git add -f "filename"), or smartgit.

Comment: Make sure to add **;** as separator.

Comment: This answer is copied across the internet, but no longer exists in IntelliJ 2021.1.3, and I have so far been unable to find an alternative.

Answer (score 59):

For Intellij IDEA 13 on OS X 10.9, do this:

- Go to `Intellij IDEA > Preferences`.
- Scroll down to the `IDE Settings` section, go to `File Types`.
- Add `*.iml` and `.idea` to the `Ignore files and folders` list box at the bottom of this window.

The project navigator will be much cleaner!

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 21):

- Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `File Types`
- Append `*.iml` to the list below "Ignore files and folders" (located at the bottom of the dialog)

Comment: For Mac OS X, one should go to `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Preferences` -> `File Types`. The rest of the instructions are valid for Mac OS X as well.

Answer (score 14):

IntelliJ 14 and 15 on Mac OS X (they've changed the hierarchy again in 14):

- Go to `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `File Types`
- Append `*.iml` to the list below "Ignore files and folders" (located at the bottom of the dialog)

Answer (score 7):

For IntelliJ 14 on Windows, go to `File->Settings->Editor->File Types`. At the bottom, append `;.idea;*.iml`.

Comment: Also applies for IntelliJ 2016

Answer (score 5):

Instead of hiding the files excluding them like folders seemed to be the better way for me.

Go to `File` > `Project Structure...` > `Settings` > `Modules`

At the bottom is a box where you can enter the file types:

[image]

Now you can use the projects "Show Options Menu" to hide and show them:

[image]

Comment: This is what I would have answered if the question was how to hide a build folder. For those who are looking for this option, you should [right click on the folder > Mark Directory as > Excluded](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/controlling-source-library-and-exclude-directories.html)

Answer (score 1):

`IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 Ultimate` on `macOS Sierra 10.12.4`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to:

> Check “Ignored files and folders” in [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#create-new-file-type) settings:

as explained in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252600/2791560), is located in the [new UI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-ui.html) as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I accept this as a separate contribution (i.e. an answer of its own), though others might disagree. However, please replace "accepted answer" by the link you get from the "Share" beneath it. And you might rephrase to make more obvious what you contribute, maybe something like "The solution to > Check “Ignored files and folders”, as in the existing answer ... link ... is done in the new UI this way: ... picture ...".

Comment: Putting files here will also make them disappear from the git tool (even if they're not gitignored)... Is there a way around this where the files can be hidden in the project view but still work in other parts of the IDE (like in the git tool)?

Answer (score -1):

Go to File -> Settings -> File Types

[image]

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer said the same 7 years ago. So what value does your answer add?