# How to hide all executable files in project list on JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, wildcard, executable, clion

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252600/5559342) I managed to hide from my project list all `*.o` and `*.lo` files (e.g. `myprogram.o`) on **CLion**. Is there a way to hide also executable files (e.g. `myprogram`) without having to type down all their names? Maybe a wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use wildcards in Settings | Editor | File Types, ignore files and folders.

Comment: What should I write for an executable as there's no extension in their names?

Comment: Just nothing. For example, you add ```myexec``` to the list.