# How to nest auto generated Dart files in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea, json-serialization

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```
// foo.dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'foo.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Foo {}
```

When I run

```
$ dart pub run build_runner build
```

It generates a `foo.g.dart` file in the same directory. But how can I combine/nest/merge/hide*/whatever this file with the original `foo.dart` file so that I don't get to see the generated file (or at least without having to click an arrow button)

[image]

<sub>*hide: in a way it can  be accessed when clicked from other code.</sub>

Comment: Is it enough to hide the generated files in the project navigator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251624/intellij-idea-hide-iml-files

Comment: @RobertSandberg No, because when I click the code (written in hidden file) from other places, that file can't be opened.

Comment: Have you considered generating the files in another directory that's out of the way? json_serializable can be configured to do this.

Comment: @hacker1024 I can do that but it will be not a good thing for two cases. 1. The `part 'foo.g.dart'` will be changed to `path '../some_dir/foo.g.dart` -- something you don't see easily in Dart. 2. As I generate more and more files from different directory, the new directory will be kind of a dumping ground and I won't be able to see  `foo.dart` and `foo.g.dart` together easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the [file nesting rules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.3/file-nesting-dialog.html) accordingly:

[image]